# Mostrar app (AndroidStudio) en Smartphone Físico

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy desarrollando mi primera app en AStudio con lenguaje Kotlin. En el emulador del AStudio (Nexus 5X - Oreo 8.0) se logra ejecutar sin problemas, pero cuando lo conecto a un smartphone físico (Samsung J7 - Marshmallow 6.0) apenas se abre me manda un mensaje, que indica que la aplicación se detuvo y se cierra.

Apenas crée la app hoy y tengo 3 activities con algunos botones e Instants que hacen saltar de una pantalla a la otra. En los dos casos no me lanza error en el AStudio.

Agradezco cualquier consejo. 
Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Podrias adjuntar el log para tener un mejor contexto y ayudarte? :)

Comment: ¿Cual es el error? para esto puede ser una cantidad considerable de problemas, por favor revisa [ask] y modifica tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Logré dar con el error, eran las imágenes.

Al momento de utilizar imágenes (jpg y png) y pegarlas en drawable, me ponía por defecto la carpeta de drawable v24. 
Cambié de carpeta a drawable y ahora me corre todo perfecto, con las imágenes de fondo, logos y las imágenes que puse.

Lo comento para quien pueda serle de ayuda en el futuro.

Saludos.